# Why are multiple list.count calls faster than a single loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, list

I have a `list` of 2-element `tuple`s generated like this:

```
import random

l = list(range(8)) * 7
random.shuffle(l)
l = list(zip(*[iter(l)] * 2))
```

The output of `l`:

```
[(1, 3),
 (6, 6),
 (1, 0),
 (4, 6),
 (1, 5),
 (7, 5),
 (4, 0),
 (5, 4),
 (4, 7),
 (4, 4),
 (0, 6),
 (2, 0),
 (3, 2),
 (7, 7),
 (6, 0),
 (2, 5),
 (1, 5),
 (0, 1),
 (0, 4),
 (5, 3),
 (7, 2),
 (3, 3),
 (6, 3),
 (2, 6),
 (7, 7),
 (5, 2),
 (3, 1),
 (2, 1)]
```

I am counting the number of occurences of a tuple `e` and its reverse:

```
e = (1, 5)
```

First, I am using `list.count`, which should have an `O(2n)` because the method is called twice, thus the list is traversed twice:

```
%timeit l.count(e) + l.count(e[::-1])
# 1.46 µs ± 11.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Then I am using a conventional `for` loop which goes through the list just once with an `O(n)`:

```
%%timeit
c = 0
for t in l:
    if t in (e, e[::-1]):
        c += 1
# 5.57 µs ± 35.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Why is the first faster than the second by a factor of `~1.5-4` even though it goes through the entire list twice?

Comment: I do not think that the way the `list` is created is relevant to the question and `l = list(zip(*[iter(l)] * 2))` might scare some people off..

Comment: @ElisByberi by the definition of the O(f(n)), that's still O(n)

Comment: Sidenote: while the `count` approach iterates twice through the loop, the single loop one does two comparisons per iteration, so that  O(2N) vs O(N) argument is not really valid.

Comment: Doesn't the interpreter need to check at each iteration of the `for loop` the type of the variables? Wouldn't this explain why the extra time?

Comment: Time complexity does not tell anything about the execution speed!

Comment: `%timeit e = set(e); sum(1 for tup in l if e.difference(tup) == set())` how about this? It has to be much faster..

Comment: Why you do not iterate twice with for loop. It will tell you that `for loop` is the bottleneck here!

Comment: @Ev.Kounis it's slowers by a factor or `~2-8`

Comment: @schwobaseggl I see what you're saying: 1 loop with 2 comparisons is the same (in terms of cost) than 2 loops with 1 comparison. In practice this is not true because it seems that iterating is more costly than comparing integers

Comment: @GPhilo You are correct! I did it on purpose. I even got a comment up-vote, hahaha. I will keep an eye on you! I was reading your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very simple answer is that `count` is implemented in pure C, and so runs faster than a Python loop. However, there are a lot of subtleties to consider.

First, you haven't written your loop in the most efficient way. Every time the expression `t in (e, e[::-1])` is executed, three things happen:

1. The `e` tuple is reversed with `e[::-1]`. Note that this only has to happen once -- you could store the result and reuse it. But right now, it's executed every time through the loop.
2. The two tuples are stored in an outer tuple. This also only has to happen once, but again, it's executed every time through the loop.
3. Finally, each item in the outer tuple is checked for equality with `t`. This does have to happen every time through the loop because the value of `t` changes each time.

Here's the result of the speed test on my computer:

```
In [6]: %%timeit
   ...: c = 0
   ...: for t in l:
   ...:     if t in (e, e[::-1]):
   ...:         c += 1
   ...: 
7.39 µs ± 43.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

To streamline this, you could just create the outer tuple once. Call it `e_test`:

```
e_test = (e, e[::-1])
```

Then things are way faster:

```
In [8]: %%timeit
    ...: c = 0
    ...: for t in l:
    ...:     if t in e_test:
    ...:         c += 1
    ...: 
3.05 µs ± 62.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

I think this might be the fastest way to implement this test using a vanilla Python for loop. However, the `count`-based solution is *still* faster!

```
In [9]: %timeit l.count(e) + l.count(e[::-1])
2.19 µs ± 62 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

We can improve on that even more by again pre-calculating the reversed tuple:

```
In [10]: e_rev = e[::-1]

In [11]: %timeit l.count(e) + l.count(e_rev)
2.06 µs ± 62.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

It's certainly true that performing two tests inside the same loop is a benefit. But the benefit is actually *very small* compared to other factors. And it's even smaller in this case because the `count` loops happen in C, which aggressively minimizes the cost of an extra for loop.

In practice, if you are deciding between doing multiple operations in one loop, and doing multiple loops, you should choose whatever is easiest to read and maintain, because 99% of the time, the overhead of multiple loops will be dramatically outweighed by the cost of the operations being performed *inside* the loop.

As a final note, here are are the best-performing alternatives to the `count`-based method that I could find. These both create a `set` instead of a tuple, which means that the `in` expression works in constant time. I had expected that using a set here wouldn't be better than using a tuple, because there are only two items to test. But it turns out that the performance is indeed better, at least on my machine:

```
In [32]: e_test_set = set(e_test)

In [33]: %timeit sum([1 for t in l if t in e_test_set])
2.34 µs ± 90.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Note that this uses an explicit list comprehension rather than passing a generator expression to `sum`. If you pass a generator expression, it's about a tenth of a microsecond slower. This is still slower than the `count`-based approach!

But once you're creating a list, it turns out you don't need to calculate the `sum` at all. The sum of a list of ones is just its length.

```
In [34]: %timeit len([1 for t in l if t in e_test_set])
2.07 µs ± 73.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Now, finally, we have a version that competes with the `count`-based approach, at least at this scale. For much larger lists, I'd expect this to be slower again, because allocating the memory for the list would take too much time.

Comment: can you please also include `sum(1 for s in l if len(e.intersection(s)) == 2)` after converting `e` to a `set`? Interested to see how it performs.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis That will not run faster than any of the two approaches already listed. Because `set.intersection` is not cheap.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye this does not make sense to me.. How about `sum(1 for s in l if e == set(s))`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Not even that. The fact that you're building sets is going to slow down the whole thing.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye [You are right](https://repl.it/repls/ExtrasmallSquareAfricanmolesnake).

Comment: how do you copy an entire notebook cell included the "In/Out" part? I've never figured out why.

Comment: btw I don't think precalculating `e[::-1]` for the `l.count` call makes any difference at all because, contrary to the loop, `e[::-1]` is only evaluated once.

Comment: @senderle it's a meta question: when you pasted your different blocks of clode they have the "In [32]" prompt from jupyter notebooks. How do you copy that part along with your code?

Comment: @senderle that's what I'm saying, you only reverse it once, it shouldn't matter whether you declare a variable to hold its value or whether you passed it directly as an argument

Comment: @senderle you just copy from the terminal then I assume?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160112/discussion-between-senderle-and-dabadaba).

Comment: How would `sum(len(e.intersection(s)) == 2 for s in l)` perform (comp or generator)?